# Any way to tell when an algebraic expression takes on values that are a square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say I have the expression $256x^2 -480x$. As a polynomial this isn't a perfect square. However that doesn't stop it from taking real values that are a perfect square for given x, such as x = 8. Is there any way to determine what other values of x make it into a perfect square? Or is it always guess and check? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming 
$256x^2-480x= b^2$

$(16x-15)^2=b^2+15^2$

Now look for Pythagorean triples involving 15,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples